# Yammer API get list of all users in All Company

Tags: rest, api, yammer

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/ does not work and only gives me users in the current user’s Yammer network. I need every single user.

If All Company had an ID I could use https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/

Moreover, https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups does not seem to have All Company within it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the backend, All Company is not actually a group. It behaves kind of like a group in the UI, but with notable difference like users not being able to leave All Company. This and other difference betray the fact that the Yammer backend does not in fact treat All Company as a normal group.

Hitting the users.json endpoint will give you data about all users in the users' current network. This list of users is the same as the list of users who are "members" of the All Company group for that network.